# I have a vector, for example, (1,2,3,4) and I want to change the numbers into string

Tags: string, matlab, vector, dictionary

I have a vector, `(1,2,3,4)` and I want to label 1 with `'AA'`, 2 with `'AB'`, 3 with `'CD'`, 4 with `'Hello'`, whatever. It should by like a vector `('AA','AB','CD','Hello')`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB has a [`Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html) [container type](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html):

```
keySet = 1:4;
valSet = {'AA','AB','CD','Hello'};
map = containers.Map(keySet,valSet);
```

Get some requested values with the [`values` method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.values.html):

```
>> vals = map.values(num2cell([3 2 1 4]))
vals = 
    'CD'    'AB'    'AA'    'Hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

easy peasy, use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-cell-array.html), for example:

```
v = {'AA','AB','CD','Hello'};
```

then try,

```
v{1}
```

etc. (note the curly brackets...{})

EDIT: this is parallel to :

```
v{1}='AA';
v{2}='AB'; ...
...
```

Comment: but I have already get a numeric vector (1,2,3,4) and I need 1 change into AA, 2 change into AB, 3 change into CD and 4 change into Hello.

Comment: is your vector just 4 elements long? please ask a more exact question...  anyway, since the # of elements is not constant (AA vs Hello), the way to do that is to create a cell array. You cant use a numeric vector to host a string of variable length. (also see my edit)

Comment: Can I do like this: use 'num2str' to change the numeric vector into a string. Assume the numeric vector is A=(1,2,3,4), then S=num2str(A) and it will change into a string vector, then how to change the string '1','2','3' and '4' to 'AA','AB','CD','Hello'? thanks.

Comment: One more step: do a multi-element indexing like `names = v(ix)` where `ix` is your numeric vector of indexes in to the list of names. Then you get a `cellstr` vector back, which is a way of storing an array of strings of different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a `cellstr` array to store the output names, and use a mapping table to translate your inputs in to outputs.

```
% List of labels that correspond to the indexes of the array
labels = {'AA', 'AB', 'CD', 'Hello'};

% Input vector
v = [1 2 3 1 4 2];

% Use multi-element indexing with () instead of {} to map them
strs = labels(v);
```

You'll get a `cellstr` array back of the same size as the input, containing the labels corresponding to the index value in each element. You can index in to it like `strs{3}` to get the individual labels out.